# Error in match.names(clabs, nmi) - Linear programming model - R

Tags: r, error-handling, linear-programming, rbind

I am applying the CCR Data Envelopment Analysis model to benchmark between stock data. To do that I am running R code from a DEA paper published [here](https://www.academia.edu/5474679/Implementing_DEA_models_in_the_R_program). This document comes with step by step instructions on how to implement the model below in R.

The mathematical formulation looks like this:

[image]

Finding the model I needed already made for me seemed too good to be true. I am getting this error when I run it:

```
Error in match.names(clabs, nmi) : names do not match previous names
```

Traceback:

```
4 stop("names do not match previous names") 
3 match.names(clabs, nmi) 
2 rbind(deparse.level, ...) 
1 rbind(aux, c(inputs[i, ], rep(0, m)))
```

My test data looks as follows:

```
> dput(testdfst)
structure(list(Name = structure(1:10, .Label = c("Stock1", "Stock2", 
"Stock3", "Stock4", "Stock5", "Stock6", "Stock7", "Stock8", "Stock9", 
"Stock10"), class = "factor"), Date = structure(c(14917, 14917, 
14917, 14917, 14917, 14917, 14917, 14917, 14917, 14917), class = "Date"), 
    `(Intercept)` = c(0.454991569278089, 1, 0, 0.459437188169979, 
    0.520523252955415, 0.827294243132907, 0.642696631099892, 
    0.166219881886161, 0.086341470900152, 0.882092217743293), 
    rmrf = c(0.373075150411683, 0.0349067218712968, 0.895550280607866, 
    1, 0.180151549474574, 0.28669170468735, 0.0939821798173586, 
    0, 0.269645291515763, 0.0900619760898984), smb = c(0.764987877309785, 
    0.509094491489323, 0.933653313048327, 0.355340700554647, 
    0.654000372286503, 1, 0, 0.221454091364611, 0.660571586102851, 
    0.545086931342479), hml = c(0.100608151187926, 0.155064872867367, 
    1, 0.464298576152336, 0.110803875258027, 0.0720803195598597, 
    0, 0.132407005239869, 0.059742053684015, 0.0661623383303703
    ), rmw = c(0.544512524466665, 0.0761995312858816, 1, 0, 0.507699534880555, 
    0.590607506295898, 0.460148690870041, 0.451871218073951, 
    0.801698199214685, 0.429094840372901), cma = c(0.671162426988512, 
    0.658898571758625, 0, 0.695830176886926, 0.567814542084284, 
    0.942862571603074, 1, 0.37571611336359, 0.72565234813082, 
    0.636762557753099), Returns = c(0.601347600017365, 0.806071701848376, 
    0.187500487065719, 0.602971876359073, 0.470386289298666, 
    0.655773224143057, 0.414258177255333, 0, 0.266112191477882, 
    1)), .Names = c("Name", "Date", "(Intercept)", "rmrf", "smb", 
"hml", "rmw", "cma", "Returns"), row.names = c("Stock1.2010-11-04", 
"Stock2.2010-11-04", "Stock3.2010-11-04", "Stock4.2010-11-04", 
"Stock5.2010-11-04", "Stock6.2010-11-04", "Stock7.2010-11-04", 
"Stock8.2010-11-04", "Stock9.2010-11-04", "Stock10.2010-11-04"
), class = "data.frame")
```

And the linear model program is this:

```
namesDMU <- testdfst[1]
inputs <- testdfst[c(4,5,6,7,8)]
outputs <- testdfst[9]

N <- dim(testdfst)[1] # number of DMU
s <- dim(inputs)[2] # number of inputs
m <- dim(outputs)[2] # number of outputs

f.rhs <- c(rep(0,N),1) # RHS constraints
f.dir <- c(rep("<=",N),"=") # directions of the constraints
aux <- cbind(-1*inputs,outputs) # matrix of constraint coefficients in (6)
for (i in 1:N) {
  f.obj <- c(0*rep(1,s),outputs[i,]) # objective function coefficients
  f.con <- rbind(aux ,c(inputs[i,], rep(0,m))) # add LHS of bTz=1
  results <-lp("max",f.obj,f.con,f.dir,f.rhs,scale=1,compute.sens=TRUE) # solve LPP
  multipliers <- results$solution # input and output weights
  efficiency <- results$objval # efficiency score
  duals <- results$duals # shadow prices
  if (i==1) {
    weights <- multipliers
    effcrs <- efficiency
    lambdas <- duals [seq(1,N)]
  } else {
    weights <- rbind(weights,multipliers)
    effcrs <- rbind(effcrs , efficiency)
    lambdas <- rbind(lambdas,duals[seq(1,N)])
  }
}
```

**Spotting the problem..**

A quick search reveals that the `rbind` function might be at fault. This is located on this line:

```
f.con <- rbind(aux ,c(inputs[i,], rep(0,m)))
```

I tried to isolate the data from the loops to see what the problem is:

```
aux <- cbind(-1*inputs,outputs)
a <- c(inputs[1,])
b <- rep(0,m)

> aux
          rmrf        smb         hml         rmw        cma   Returns
1  -0.37307515 -0.7649879 -0.10060815 -0.54451252 -0.6711624 0.6013476
2  -0.03490672 -0.5090945 -0.15506487 -0.07619953 -0.6588986 0.8060717
3  -0.89555028 -0.9336533 -1.00000000 -1.00000000  0.0000000 0.1875005
4  -1.00000000 -0.3553407 -0.46429858  0.00000000 -0.6958302 0.6029719
5  -0.18015155 -0.6540004 -0.11080388 -0.50769953 -0.5678145 0.4703863
6  -0.28669170 -1.0000000 -0.07208032 -0.59060751 -0.9428626 0.6557732
7  -0.09398218  0.0000000  0.00000000 -0.46014869 -1.0000000 0.4142582
8   0.00000000 -0.2214541 -0.13240701 -0.45187122 -0.3757161 0.0000000
9  -0.26964529 -0.6605716 -0.05974205 -0.80169820 -0.7256523 0.2661122
10 -0.09006198 -0.5450869 -0.06616234 -0.42909484 -0.6367626 1.0000000

> a
$rmrf
[1] 0.3730752

$smb
[1] 0.7649879

$hml
[1] 0.1006082

$rmw
[1] 0.5445125

$cma
[1] 0.6711624
```

I also looked at this:

```
> identical(names(aux[1]), names(a[1]))
[1] TRUE
```

Column and row names are unimportant to me as long as the problem is calculated so I decided to try remove them. This one works but doesn't solve the problem.

```
rownames(testdfst) <- NULL
```

Looking at the contents of `a` and `aux`, maybe the problem lies with the column names.

`colnames(testdfst) <- NULL` does not work. It deletes everything in my data-frame. It could maybe... provide a solution to the problem if I can figure out how to remove the column names.

Comment: `rbind`ing is like stacking data frames or matrices, so when you do that, r does minimal checks to see if the columns have the same names. if the types are different, it might throw a warning, for example if you combine factors with different levels, but still do the binding. if the names are different, it will throw an error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you correctly identified, the following line is giving you the trouble:

```
i <- 1
f.con <- rbind(aux ,c(inputs[i,], rep(0,m))) # add LHS of bTz=1
# Error in match.names(clabs, nmi) : names do not match previous names
```

You can use the `str` function to see the structure of each element of this expression:

```
str(aux)
# 'data.frame': 10 obs. of  6 variables:
#  $ rmrf   : num  -0.3731 -0.0349 -0.8956 -1 -0.1802 ...
#  $ smb    : num  -0.765 -0.509 -0.934 -0.355 -0.654 ...
#  $ hml    : num  -0.101 -0.155 -1 -0.464 -0.111 ...
#  $ rmw    : num  -0.5445 -0.0762 -1 0 -0.5077 ...
#  $ cma    : num  -0.671 -0.659 0 -0.696 -0.568 ...
#  $ Returns: num  0.601 0.806 0.188 0.603 0.47 ...

str(inputs[i,])
# 'data.frame': 1 obs. of  5 variables:
#  $ rmrf: num 0.373
#  $ smb : num 0.765
#  $ hml : num 0.101
#  $ rmw : num 0.545
#  $ cma : num 0.671

str(c(inputs[i,], rep(0, m)))
# List of 6
#  $ rmrf: num 0.373
#  $ smb : num 0.765
#  $ hml : num 0.101
#  $ rmw : num 0.545
#  $ cma : num 0.671
#  $     : num 0
```

Now you can see that the list you are trying to combine with `rbind` has different names from the data frame it's being combined with. Probably the simplest way to proceed would be to pass a vector as the new row instead of a list, which you can accomplish by converting `inputs[i,]` to a matrix with `as.matrix`:

```
str(c(as.matrix(inputs[i,]), rep(0, m)))
#  num [1:6] 0.373 0.765 0.101 0.545 0.671 ...
```

This will cause the code to work without an error:

```
f.con <- rbind(aux, c(as.matrix(inputs[i,]), rep(0, m)))
```

A few unsolicited R coding tips -- instead of `dim(x)[1]` and `dim(x)[2]` to get the number of rows and columns, most would find it more readable to do `nrow(x)` and `ncol(x)`. Also, building objects in a for loop by `rbind`ing one row at a time can be very inefficient -- you can read more about that in the second circle of [the R Inferno](http://www.burns-stat.com/pages/Tutor/R_inferno.pdf).